# $ symbol in C variable names

Tags: c, variables

I would like to help me with the following code:

```
int main()
{
   int a = 3;
   int $ab = 15;

   printf("%d %d\n", a, $ab);

   return 0;    
}
```

In this very simple code I declared the $ab variable which supposed to be invalid. Instead, the program is compiled and run successfully.

Can anybody explain this?

Comment: It's allowed, that's it. But not encouraged.

Comment: @MarounMaroun how and why is that allowed?

Comment: You know, the C standard is more what you'd call "guidelines" than actual rules (Barbossa, PotC)