# Why can identifiers contain '$' in C?

Tags: c

Recently I saw code like this:

```
int $ = 123;
```

So why can '$' be in an identifier in C?

Is it the same in C++?

Comment: It is an extension to the C language that many compilers implement by default. If you don't want it, you need to disable it explicitly. For gcc and clang, it would be an aptly named `-fno-dollars-in-identifiers` command line option.

Comment: [$ symbol in C variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28426733/995714), [What are the '@' and '$' for in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18494262/995714)

Comment: Tangential note: The VMS operating system was very fond of having dollar signs all over the place — calling the boot device SYS$SYSDEVICE and that sort of thing. I suspect that e.g. gcc acquired the habit of allowing $ in order to fit into that environment.

Comment: @Jens: If a C implementation allows `$` in identifiers, that is conforming to the C standard, and, when a program uses `$` in identifiers in an C implementation that allows it, that is also conforming to the C standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not good practice. Generally, you should only use alphanumeric characters and underscores in identifiers (`[a-z][A-Z][0-9]_`).

### Surface Level

Unlike in other languages (bash, perl), C does not use `$` to denote the usage of a variable. As such, it is technically valid. As of C++ 17, this is standards conformant, see Draft n4659. In C it most likely falls under C11, 6.4.2. This means that it does seem to be supported by modern compilers.

As for your C++ question, lets test it!

```cpp
int main(void) {
    int $ = 0;
    return $;
}
```

On GCC/G++/Clang/Clang++, this indeed compiles, and runs just fine.

### Deeper Level

Compilers take source code, lex it into a token stream, put that into an abstract syntax tree (AST), and then use that to generate code (e.g. assembly/LLVM IR). Your question really only revolves around the first part (e.g. lexing).

The grammar (thus the lexer implementation) of C/C++ does not treat `$` as special, unlike commas, periods, skinny arrows, etc... As such, you may get an output from the lexer like this from the below c code:

```cpp
int i_love_$ = 0;
```

After the lexer, this becomes a token steam like such:

```
["int", "i_love_$", "=", "0"]
```

If you where to take this code:

```cpp
int i_love_$,_and_.s = 0;
```

The lexer would output a token steam like:

```
["int", "i_love_$", ",", "_and_", ".", "s", "=", "0"]
```

As you can see, because C/C++ doesn't treat characters like $ as special, it is processed differently than other characters like periods.

Comment: See C11, 6.4.2. It probably falls in "other implementation-defined characters"

Answer (score 2):

The 2018 C standard says in 6.4.2 1 that an identifier consists of a *nondigit* character followed zero or more *nondigit* or *digit* characters, where the *nondigit* characters are:

- one of the characters `_`, `a` through `z`, or `A` through `Z`,
- a *universal-character-name*, which is `\u` followed by four hexadecimal digits or `\U` followed by eight hexadecimal digits, that is outside certain ranges<sup>1</sup>, or
- implementation-defined characters.

The digit characters are `0` through `9`.

Taking GCC as an example, its documentation says [these additional characters are defined in its preprocessor section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Identifiers-implementation.html#Identifiers-implementation), and that section says [GCC accepts `$` and the characters that correspond to the universal character names](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html#Implementation-defined-behavior).<sup>2</sup> Thus, allowing `$` is a choice made by the compiler implementors.

Draft n4659 of the 2017 C++ standard has the same rules, in clause 5.10 [lex.name], except it limits the universal character names further.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> These `\u` and `\U` forms allow you to write any character as a hexadecimal code. The excluded ranges are those in C’s *basic character set* and codes reserved for control characters and special uses.

<sup>2</sup> The “universal character names” are the `\u` and `\U` forms. The characters that correspond to them are the characters that those forms represent. For example, `π` is a universal character, and `\u03c0` is the universal character name for it.